# TSQL Max Function not working right

Tags: join, max

Using TSQL - 
Trying to get most recent MAX(HAR_ASSESSMENT.SESSION_DATE) but my query is returning the oldest assessment date instead of the most recent.  I think it has something to do with the SERVICE_DELIVERIES join and parameter...any suggestions would be appreciated.

```
**SELECT
  HAR_ASSESSMENTS.NEXT_SESSION_DATE
  ,HAR_CONSUMERS.CLIENT_ID
  ,HAR_CONSUMERS.FULL_NAME
  ,MAX (HAR_SERVICE_DELIVERIES.SERVICE_PERIOD_START) AS Max_SERVICE_PERIOD_START
  ,HAR_SERVICE_DELIVERIES.SERVICE
  ,HAR_ASSESSMENTS.ASSESSFORM_NAME
  ,MAX(HAR_ASSESSMENTS.SESSION_DATE) AS Max_SESSION_DATE
  ,HAR_SERVICE_DELIVERIES.AGENCY
  ,HAR_SERVICE_DELIVERIES.PROVIDER
  ,HAR_SERVICE_DELIVERIES.FUND_IDENTIFIER
FROM
  HAR_CONSUMERS
  INNER JOIN HAR_ASSESSMENTS
    ON HAR_CONSUMERS.CONSUMER_UUID = HAR_ASSESSMENTS.CONSUMER_UUID
  INNER JOIN HAR_SERVICE_DELIVERIES
    ON HAR_CONSUMERS.CONSUMER_UUID = HAR_SERVICE_DELIVERIES.CONSUMER_UUID
WHERE
  HAR_SERVICE_DELIVERIES.SERVICE_PERIOD_START >= @SERVICE_PERIOD_START
  AND HAR_SERVICE_DELIVERIES.SERVICE_PERIOD_START <= @SERVICE_PERIOD_START2
  AND HAR_SERVICE_DELIVERIES.SERVICE IN (@SERVICE)
  AND HAR_ASSESSMENTS.ASSESSFORM_NAME IN (@ASSESSFORM_NAME)
  AND HAR_ASSESSMENTS.AGENCY IN (@AGENCY)
GROUP BY
HAR_ASSESSMENTS.NEXT_SESSION_DATE
  ,HAR_CONSUMERS.CLIENT_ID
  ,HAR_CONSUMERS.FULL_NAME
  ,HAR_SERVICE_DELIVERIES.SERVICE
  ,HAR_ASSESSMENTS.ASSESSFORM_NAME
  ,HAR_SERVICE_DELIVERIES.AGENCY
  ,HAR_SERVICE_DELIVERIES.PROVIDER
  ,HAR_SERVICE_DELIVERIES.FUND_IDENTIFIER**
```

Comment: Does the query only return a single row?  Or are you only grabbing the first row?  If so, you can simply sort in reverse order: `ORDER BY MAX(HAR_ASSESSMENTS.SESSION_DATE) DESC`.

Comment: The query is returning one row per client ID.  At this time its pulling the MIN session_date instead of the MAX.  Not sure why.  Some clients have 20+ assessment dates and I only want the query to show me the most recent.

Comment: It looks like you are grouping by some columns in the same table(s) as the ones you are aggregating with `MAX`.  This is likely the issue - does your output query really give you only row per client?  It seems like it would be giving you multiple rows per client.